# Hooke's law as approximation of general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, elasticity

I have seen how in the paper [The Mechanics of Spacetime - A Solid Mechanics Perspective on the Theory of General Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07655) by Tenev and Horstemeyer Hooke's law is written in tensorial form, and I was wondering how to derive it from the Einstein field equation. The product of 2 Christoffel symbols is an infinitesimal of second order so we can put it as zero so the Ricci tensor depends by the derivative of Christoffel symbols but there is a problem for me of understanding:
isn't in this case the Ricci tensor proportional to the metric in order to obtain the Hooke's law we have in the paper?

Comment: I tried to read the paper and it seems they derived the Einstein Hilbert action using Hookes law and a bunch of postulates. Do you want to do this in reverse ?

Comment: no the Hooke's elastic law from einstein field equation

Comment: But Hooke's law is a constitutive law. You need to make some assumptions analogous to a constitutive law?

Comment: the assumptions are small speeds, equilibrium and almost flat space, I just don't understand why the Ricci tensor is in this case proportional to the metric

Comment: It seems to be a quadratic expression of second fundamental form near 2.18 and linear in derivative of strain in 3.7. Don't see where it is proportional. I give up now.

Answer (score -1):

Very cool post! I had (and still have) a very similar idea - meaning that Einstain and Hooke are qite close :) It remains to investigate the string theory in the same way - a subject on which I have some ideas. So I am only a mathematician and the things are slowly moving. Shortly speacing, all in the Universe depend of the properties of the vacuum.
Regards,
Vladimir Todorov

Comment: Kleinert wrote a whole book about the subject more than 30 year ago: https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/0356#t=aboutBook